# Run time dependency vs Compile time dependency

Tags: java, dependencies

They are both common in an application. But it is possible to replace compile time dependencies with run time dependencies and I see a lot of code doing that. For example, use reflections. What's the cons and pros of them? Should we avoid compile time(run time) dependencies as much as possible?

Comment: ... Reflection is slow.

Comment: @DaveNewton True. Good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of compile vs runtime would be slf4j-api which is used on compile time and slf4j-log4j on runtime. In this example we are talking about static binding which is the fastest way to go.

Dynamic linking like commons-logging to log4j, would be your reflection, because the call is made dynamically on runtime. Worst way to go, but sometimes necessary and some times very elegant if you think about the commons-lang Equal and HashBuilder functions.

Refection gives you a neat power to call what you do not know at the time of building, but it should be confined to framework code. Some would call it the highest level of programmer's lazyness :-)

So. If you do know, what you are about to invoke, or you have a strong picture of what you want to call, use Interfaces instead. It's way faster, predictable and secure. Think about IoC.

To add to your confusion, there are also runtime dependencies, which are not met on runtime. For example the log4j context listener requires a servlet implementation. But if you are not invoking it on runtime, you must not bother. Hibernat has the dom4 dependency, but if you use annotation s only, you don't need it. 
Then you can deliberately shadow classes to inject it into the package structure. This comes handy if your library what written with classes that use default visibility. But AFAIK this is static binding. Note: In a security context, this would be called the Mix-and-Match attack.

To come back to you question: use static binding whenever is is possible.